# Common terminology for a "padded" sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, reference-request

Consider a sequence $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and the "padded" version $\hat x = (x_1,x_2,x_3,0,0,\ldots)$ with zeros all the way to infinity.

What is the standard way to refer to $\hat x$ with respect to $x$? I have searched for "padded sequence" and "infinite extension of a sequence" but haven't found much. Perhaps making a connection to mappings (every sequence is a mapping) will reveal the correct terminology? Any relevant terms would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know of a standard notation for this.  I think of this as applying the natural inclusion map $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^\infty$.  Often in such a case authors will "abuse notation", identifying $x$ with $\hat{x}$ and using the same notation for both.  If it is important to distinguish them, your $\hat{x}$ notation is fine.

Comment: @JairTaylor Thanks. I found someone refer to them as "dull sequences" (see http://people.reed.edu/~mayer/math112.html/html2/node10.html) but they appear to be the only ones using that terminology...

Comment: I haven't heard of "dull sequences".  I would call them sequences with *finite support*, the support of a sequence being the non-zero terms.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space) uses the notation $c_{00}$ for the set of these sequences; I also see $\mathbb{R}^{\oplus \mathbb{N}}$, e.g., [here](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~lior/teaching/1314/412_W14/Notes/InfiniteDimensions.pdf).